# Underpants Gnomes Bug

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

During the quest 'Phase 1' for the Underpants Gnomes in Stick of Truth, I have definitely collected all five pairs of underpants, but my quest journal has only logged four pairs!? Quest items cannot be sold, so I can't have lost them... Any ideas?

Comment: Tried double-checking if you have indeed [got all the underpants](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159591/4797)? Related: [Where are the underwear?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159591/4797)

Comment: Yeah, I've treble checked. They're in: Stan's room, Kyles room, Stan's parents room, Cartman's moms room and the Star Trek kids room.

Comment: It's anything but ideal, but if you have an older save from before collecting the underpants, you could always try collecting them again. It also might be relevant to mention what point you are at in the game to help narrow down the bug.

Comment: I collected my first pair from Cartman's moms room in day one. The pretty much straight after I received the quest.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine had a similar issue. He was in day 2, and got too many friends. The game automatically forwarded him to day 3 without going through the proper quests.

I believe this is similar to what you are experiencing. If you get to a certain point in the game with too many friends, items or whatever, it "shoots you forward" without counting anything properly.

Unfortunately for my friend, he was missing a key item to advance in the story. As for you, you just miss out on 1 friend (an achievement in this case).

Comment: Collecting the underwear is required to advanced the story.  You don't get the spell to shrink yourself otherwise.

Comment: On the PC version, you get the spell to shrink yourself when you get the quest to find the underwear.

Comment: This is the same for every version of the game, but in this case the game bugged out for the key item.